# How to find shift between three consecutive rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"event": ["Search Executed", "Search Results Returned", "Result List Clicked", "Result List Clicked", "Document Action", "Result List Clicked", "Returned Results", "Search Results Returned", "Result List Clicked", "Preview", "Open", "Search Executed", "Returned Results", "Document Action"]})
print(df)

                      event

0           Search Executed
1   Search Results Returned
2       Result List Clicked
3       Result List Clicked
4           Document Action
5       Result List Clicked
6          Returned Results
7   Search Results Returned
8       Result List Clicked
9                   Preview
10                     Open
11          Search Executed
12         Returned Results
13          Document Action
```

I am looking for whether these two patterns exists in the dataframe.

Pattern1:

```
event

Search Executed
Search Results Returned
Result List Clicked
```

Pattern 2:

```
event

Search Executed
Returned Results
Document Action
```

If either of these patterns exist, then I want to extract that part only. So in this case I want two outputs.
Output 1:

```
                      event

0           Search Executed
1   Search Results Returned
2       Result List Clicked
```

Output 2:

```
                      event

11          Search Executed
12         Returned Results
13          Document Action
```

Is there an elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the letters to their ASCII code using [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord), then compute a `diff` to build a group (consecutive letters give a diff of `1`). Finally use `groupby` to split to dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"event": ["A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "E"]})
group = df['event'].map(ord).diff().ne(1).cumsum()

dfs = [g for _, g in df.groupby(group)]
```

output:

```
[  event
 0     A
 1     B
 2     C,

   event
 3     B
 4     C,

   event
 5     E]
```

If you want to group when the letters come back to previous ones (so that C->E remained grouped), change the `group` to use `lt(0)`:

```
group = df['event'].map(ord).diff().lt(0).cumsum()
```

output:

```
[  event
 0     A
 1     B
 2     C,

   event
 3     B
 4     C
 5     E]
```

Comment: The events are not exactly as I named them. This events value could contain more than 30 characters and two different events could start with same letter. Will this solution still hold?

Comment: @supratimsaha can you provide a clear example? with occurrences than should and should not restart the group?

Comment: I edited the question, let me know if anything doesn't make sense

Comment: @supratimsaha this is now a completely different question ;)

Comment: Yeah I know. I should have framed the question correctly, sorry for that.